# How to send files (Jpegs or Pngs) over RS-422 using Python on a raspberry Pi

Tags: python, interface, raspberry-pi

I am looking into how to send data (specifical images either in JPEG or PNG format) over RS-422 on a raspberry pi using Python possibly using this pi hat(https://thepihut.com/products/rs422-rs485-serial-hat?variant=20063170003006&currency=GBP&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gclid=CjwKCAjwj975BRBUEiwA4whRB9LAcfWwfiqiYqhTq2LgqIY-ZZQTmo0pbvs0UJRRxbyOzjs9StNstRoC_lUQAvD_BwE) Though I am not married to the idea of using this hat.

I have been doing a lot of googling and I even been reading a book on instrumentation interfaces but I am still struggling to find any good information or tutorials on this.

If anyone could offer any advice as to a starting point as to how to figure out how to do this i would very much appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: You can connect arduino to your raspberry pi and use an arduino-to-rs232 adapter. It would be a lot cheaper

Comment: This should give you an idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536518/2836621